# code for a word finder where it displays the position of a word

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
sentence='ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY'
word=[]
pos=0
choice=''
while choice!='q':
    print(sentence)
    word=sentence.split(' ')
    choice=input('what word do you want to find').upper()
    for pos in range(len(word)):
        if choice==word[pos]:
            print('The word '  + str(choice)+  ' occurs in the ' + str(pos +1) + ' th position ')
```

I have this piece of code which outputs to the user the position of the word they are trying to find. I have the code working but for my evaluation i dont really get how **if choice==word[pos]:** works. If anyone could explain this to me it would be much appreciated

Comment: Seems to be a form of iteration? Not familiar with python but it seems to loop through your `word[]` array after splitting the string by `' '` and then tries to match each word to the user's entered string. This may help: http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook006.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially pos is set to 0. 
Say your search word is COUNTRY.
You are storing the search word in choice variable with the statement

```
choice=input('what word do you want to find').upper()
```

word will be an array of objects holding words from the sentence.

```
word = sentence.split('')
```

You are doing a for loop from 0 to length of the word in the statement

```
for pos in range(len(word)):

if choice==word[pos]:
```

the above statement is just a comparison statement between two strings. In our example, choice=COUNTRY, word[0]=ASK, so it will skip and move to the next iteration till the choice and word[pos] matches.

Here, pos value is the position of the string that you searched.

Hope it cleared your doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You loop over all word positions in your sentence, and compare if the input word is the same as the word in this position. If pos is 2 for example, you look at the third word in the sentence and see if it is equal to the input word. If it is you print this given statement.

The word object is a list that looks like this after splitting on spaces (' '):

```
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for pos in range(len(word)):
```

You are iterating over the position, first pos = 0, then pos = 1 ect.

```
word[pos]
```

is the word in the pos position (since you split the sentences to a list of words).

so when you check:

```
choice==word[pos]
```

you check if the choice is in position pos.

Hope thats helps

Comment: Thanks it really did